# Rails error: `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a working Rails project. I'm adding a feature that adds a secondary relationship between two tables. They have a primary join table, and I'm adding a second one for a different relationship:

in Clients:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports, :join_table => 'reports_clients'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :managed_reports, :class => :reports, :join_table => 'client_report_manager'
```

in Reports:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, :join_table => 'reports_clients'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :client_managers, :class => :clients, :join_table => 'client_report_manager'
```

I'm getting the error above:  `'block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: class (ArgumentError)`

At least I'm pretty sure that that's where the error is... The `reports_clients` relationship works fine. the new `client_report_manager` is the thing that is breaking it, I think.

Comment: I think you meant to use `:class_name => 'Report'` (or `Reports` depending on how you named you model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: class (ArgumentError)

The problem is that `class` is **not a valid key** here. It should be `class_name`. Also the value for the `class_name` should be the **name of the class**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :managed_reports, :class_name => 'Report', :join_table => 'client_report_manager'

has_and_belongs_to_many :client_managers, :class_name => 'Client', :join_table => 'client_report_manager'
```